# Did Plato believe in institution of marriage?

Tags: reference-request, marriage

From [this](http://christianobserver.net/platos-role-in-the-new-world-order/) link, I've found this

> all these women shall be wives in common to all the men, and not one
>   of them shall live privately with any man; the children too should be
>   held in common so that no parent shall know which is his own
>   offspring, and no child shall know his parent.” This belief is
>   associated with a need for eugenics, as “the best men must cohabit
>   with the best women in as many cases as possible and the worst with
>   the worst in the fewest, and that the offspring of the one must be
>   reared and that of the other not, if the flock is to be as perfect as
>   possible.” More pernicious still is his prescription for infanticide:
>   “The offspring of the inferior, and any of those of the other sort who
>   are born defective, they will properly dispose of in secret, so that
>   no one will know what has become of them. That is the condition of
>   preserving the purity of the guardians’ breed.”

Does this block appear in The Republic? Did Plato criticize or reject institution of marriage?

Comment: There is a "philosophy" stack exchange, where this would be better placed.

Comment: @JamesK I think philosophy is more about metaphysics.  While Plato is best known as a philosopher, his opinions did touch on politics and social order in general.  Since the institution of marriage is currently part of the political discussion, this is on topic.

Comment: It's politics.  Marriage laws are still politically controversial today, and there are still [those who wish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_racism) that people could be bred, (and culled!), just like dogs and horses.

Comment: See my answer at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55717/did-plato-not-believe-in-institution-of-marriage ... Plato was not against "sacred" matrimony and he was firmly intolerant of "licentiousness".

Comment: Normally I'd vote to reopen this, but since the exact same question was posted to philosophy SE....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plato's rules for marriage and children:](https://www.jstor.org/stable/636442?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

In the "guardian" class, men and women are held in common.

In other classes unions of man (age 25 to 45) and woman (20 to 40) to be decided by the archeons (but under the pretence of unions decided by lottery)

No children to be born outside of these unions. Nor any kind of sex outside of these unions.

Unions to take place at special ceremonies.

Any children that are born outside of state wedlock or to unfit parents are to be killed.

So, for the higher members of his society, he holds that men and women should be held in common. For lower members of society he has a form of marriage, but with couples chosen by the state, not by the families or by the bride and groom.

Comment: Interesting link to 'The Marriage Laws in Plato's Republic
G. M. A. Grube
The Classical Quarterly
Vol. 21, No. 2 (Apr., 1927), pp. 95-99', **but** 4/5ths of it is behind a jstor login/paywall frontend.   A less restricted citation would be better.

Comment: Whoa, the author of that article was a very radical person, George M. A. Grube.  I would definitely get a second opinion on what Plato is supposed to have claimed in the Republic.

Comment: ...but he didn't seem to have it wrong, from my reading.  Scary stuff--- they openly anticipated the false propaganda that would be required in order to get their utopian vision kicked-off!

Comment: @elliot https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55717/did-plato-not-believe-in-institution-of-marriage

Comment: From further reading, "having wives in common" appears never to be construed as implying "licentiousness" or violating "sacred" matrimony.  Guys, this was never written as anything other than State-arranged marriages.